# SurfaceView inside TabHost causes crash

Tags: android, android-tabhost, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView-derived class in an Activity inside a TabHost (like the HelloTabWidget sample). The SurfaceView I'm using comes with the excellent andrtoid-flot-chart library: [FlotChartContainer.java](http://code.google.com/p/flot-android-chart/source/browse/branches/flot_android1.0/src/com/flotandroidchart/flot/FlotChartContainer.java)

When I switch between the tabs, everything works. However, as soon as the tab containing this view has been initialized (e.g. shown) my application is doomed. It will crash whenever the following occurs:

**Pressing Home button**
When I re-open my application, it crashes due to an *IllegalStateException* in surfaceCreated().

**Starting new activity**
When I start a new activity (*startActivity*) and press the Back button (this invokes my SurfaceView's *surfaceDestroyed*...?!), it crashes due to an *IllegalStateException* in surfaceCreated().

- I'm targeting API level 7 (Android 2.1).
- The code works when TabHost is not used.
- Switching between tabs does not invoke surfaceDestroyed(). Instead, onPause() and onResume() are used.
- When an activity is finished, surfaceDestroyed() is called even if it is not in the active tab.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `surfaceChanged()` and  `surfaceDestroyed()` I finally came up with an ugly solution that solves this particular case:

- No XML! View created programmatically.
- Re-create and re-add the view in `onResume()`.
- Remove the view in `onPause()`.

@Karthi_heno
You pointed me in the right direction. The key is to handle `onPause()` properly. However, I ran into weird delays (some 10 seconds, probably due to `Canvas.lockCanvas()` calls)...

Answer (score 0):

Check activity life cycle in android , while onPause() , onStop() , onDestroy() , destroy the surface view which has been used in your application , and recreate surface in onResume() , then it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I believe that would work. But how do you destroy a surface loaded from an xml layout? Is that good practice?

Comment: i don`t know whether it is good one , but i hope it will help your problem , fro my camera surface view i handle in that way only, like onDestroy() camera.stopPreview() and onResume() camera.startpreview().

Comment: Given a SurfaceView with a drawing thread, should I destroy the thread entirely in onPause and re-create it in onResume? I tried this earlier and mostly got a black screen. Do you have to recreate the SurfaceHolder when resumed?